# How do I introduce impedance in an AC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, ac, impedance

Complete noob here so please bear with me.

I want to know how to and how much impedance to introduce in a single phase AC circuit of 220v and 50hz so that I can bring it down to 100v. My load is an AC single phase motor.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely this is not actually what you want to do at all. A transformer would be the way to do it. There are two reason not to use a series impedance. First is that the impedance would likely dissipate a lot of power, and second is that a fixed impedance will not create the correct 100V output as the motor current varies. You really need a fixed 100V input. By the way are you sure the motor is 100V, and not, say, 120V?

Comment: @mkeith Its actually a 220v motor, but I want to run it at 100v. I wanted to bring its speed down, plus I thought it might be a great opportunity to learn about impedance.

Comment: Well, it would be good to know what type of motor it is. Some motors can be speed controlled by varying the voltage. But induction motors, for example, need to have voltage and frequency varied for speed control.

Comment: The question still doesn't say what type of motor it is. Any way you could edit the question to add that information?

Answer (score 4):

**Please don't, it really doesn't work this way**

I appreciate your noob status and it's great that you are asking here ! Connecting a 100V load to a 220V is fairly complicated, a simple voltage divider is NOT the way to do this. And if you get it wrong there is signficant risk of severe damage to the motor or the power supply. Even worse: there is significant risk of damage to people including yourself.

The proper way to do this would be a transformer but if you don't know what this or how to properly specify and size it, you shouldn't be using one.

Comment: I do have a transformer. But, I wanted to learn and play around.

Comment: @pumpitup9090 220V is no place to play around. It's where noobs go to die. Play with less than 48V, your life will be longer.

Comment: Health advise: Don't play around with 220V unless you know what will happen.

Comment: I understand your concern. but isn't this how you learn? I'll take all the precautions like, insulating gloves, turn off the mains (breaker) first.

Comment: No, you learn by taking a few classes so you can understand the specifications of an transformer. Once you do then you FIRST design this on paper, verify with calculations that you do NOT exceed any safety or max ratings and THEN you prototype it and bring it up carefully, verifying each calcualtion with a measurement. Even if you don't get shocked stuff still can melt, blow up or catch on fire. This is too dangerous to just play around with. If you want to play around, keep it to 5V or less until you have blown up a few parts and get a feel for it. Then go up to +-15V

Comment: I think this is where I mention that I'm a mechanical engineering student and I have/am studying electrical circuits and machinery.

Comment: Sorry, no offense intended. AC engines have a pretty complicated load behavior, that's why a series impedance is a non starter. If you feel you understand this enough to properly size a transformer using it's data sheet, than give it a go. You can also just really oversize the transformer to be safe.  We all make mistakes (I sure do) and it's a good idea to make the first rookie mistakes on low voltage circuit. Safer and cheaper.